# Twisted Could not accept new connection (EMFILE)

Tags: python, linux, twisted

Could not accept new connection (EMFILE) - this message append in log every seconds many times, and server don't accent connection. It is happened after 2000+ connections.

```
 #lsof | wc -l
2309

 #ulimit -n
655360

 #uname -a
Linux .... 2.6.39-400.215.11.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 13:07:26 PDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I use EPollReactor (twisted 12.1.0):

from twisted.internet import epollreactor
epollreactor.install()

what can i do?
sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

You are running out of available file descriptors, either on a per-user, per-process or per-computer basis.

You may need to change some `ulimit` or `sysctl` parameters to increase these limits.

Depending on your operating system this may be slightly different.  For example, [here's the relevant chapter of the FreeBSD handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-sysctl.html) about tuning limits with sysctl.

Comment: I already increase nfile to 655360 in /etc/security/limits.conf
`
    root soft  nofile 655360
    root hard  nofile 655360
`
deamon work as root

Comment: # cat /proc/*deamon_pid*/limits  
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit               Units  
     Max open files            655360               655360               files

Answer (score 0):

Increasing limits doesn't fix the problem, it delays it. 
There is only one issue, you must queueing requests and wait when you are out of sockets or file descriptors until some become available again.
Look at https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue which does the job.